# Determining independence of random variables from joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, marginal-distribution

I am working on the problem below and have a question about the note that is provided.

[image: Problem]

I know that independent random variables must satisfy the following;
$$
f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{_X}(x)f_{_Y}(y)
$$
where $f_{_X}(x)$ and $f_{_Y}(y)$ are the marginal PDFs of the joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)$

From this fact we can make the following observations;

i.
$$
f_{_X}(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} (2x + y)dy = 2x+0.5, ~~~~~~ 
f_{_Y}(y) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} (2x + y)dx = y+1
$$
Since $f_{XY}(x,y) \neq f_{_X}(x)f_{_Y}(y) $ we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

ii.
$$
f_{_X}(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} 2 \lambda e^{-\lambda x} y ~ dy = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, ~~~~~~ 
f_{_Y}(y) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} 2 \lambda e^{- \lambda x} y ~ dx = 2y
$$
Since $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{_X}(x)f_{_Y}(y) $ we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

iii.
$$
f_{_X}(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{2}} 2 x y ~ dy = 2x, ~~~~~~ 
f_{_Y}(y) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} 2 x y ~ dx = y
$$
Since $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{_X}(x)f_{_Y}(y) $ we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I know how to do the problem if I have the marginal PDFs; however, I haven't a clue as to how to determine independence if I don't. The note indicates that it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following result:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ random variables with joint density $f(x,y)$ positive if and only if $(x,y)\in [a,b]\times [c,d]$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Then, $$X\perp Y\iff f(x,y)=g(x)h(y),$$where $\perp$ denote independence between random variables and $g$ is non-negative function of $x$ and $h$ is non-negative function of $y$.

The result above indicates that we do not need under certain conditions to find the marginal densities, as the given problem indicates.

For example, notice we have

- $f(x,y)=2xy$ is positive for $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [0,\sqrt{2}]$ and $f(x,y)=0$ in otherwise. Also, $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ where

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x,\quad 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1,\\0,\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}, \quad h(y)=\begin{cases}2y,\quad 0\leqslant y\leqslant \sqrt{2},\\0,\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Thus, $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for showing me this relationship. This was not discussed in class, nor is it in the textbook (I just checked to see if I had missed it). I see how I can apply it to all of the joint PDFs given above.

Comment: +1, This makes a lot of sense, but how do you show using this idea that rv's are dependent? If you cannot express something as a product, it would not mean such a thing is impossible, perhaps you just lack the skills for finding the correct transformation?...

Comment: Thank you very much. I take your point, the result should be useful for ii) and iii) but for i) it is better to use the definition. Of course one could prove that the only functions satisfying the relation $\phi(x)+\varphi(y)=\phi(x)\varphi(y)$ are constants, so there are no such particular searched functions for i), I think. @gt6989b